# Cycles Rendering in Blender

Tags: fonts, blender, subpixel-rendering

I have Blender 2.79, and for some reason, in the rendering options the Cycles renderer disappeared. There are only 2 options for me, the Blender Render and the Blender Game. How can I download Cycles, or is it even possible? How could I solve this problem, because the basic Renderer program doesn't make such nice pictures as the Cycles renderer.

Answer (score 0):

While cycles is an official part of blender, it is technically being provided as an addon.

The cycles addon needs to be enabled for it to be available. Open *File->User Preferences* and find the cycles addon and enable it.

[image: enabling the cycles addon]

If cycles cannot be found in the addons list, then you may have deleted blenders addon files and should look at re-installing blender.